# SqlServer identity naming convention

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions

I have  table **Widgets** and table **Persons**

both of them contains Identity column ( seed)

*what is the recommended naming convention for the identity column ?*

**is** it "`id`" ( for both tables ) :

```
Widgets.Id
Persons.Id
```

**or**

```
Widgets.WidgetId
Persons.PersonId
```

Is there advantages / disadvantages in the former  compare to the latter ?

Comment: This has been asked before on [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice), unfortunately I can't send it there. It's just too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TimPost Hi , Still dont understand why you closed it....i just asked a question  because I had a dilemma.... never meant to start a debate...

Comment: @RoyiNamir it was never a debate. This is how the Stack Exchange network works. You're fine.

Comment: @RoyiNamir The text under the close reason is applied automatically if that close reason is selected. The question is interesting, it's just not a good fit for the site. We do very well with questions that result in a single, technically 'best' answer. Votes on this type of question basically just indicate 'yes, that's how I do it'. programmers.stackexchange.com was established to provide a venue for real world issues that don't quite fit on Stack Overflow. You didn't do anything wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one case where I'd go for redundancy and have Thing.ThingID
Otherwise you have to alias it *everywhere* when you JOIN

Note: this was already done to **death and beyond** on programmers.se:
[Why is naming a table's Primary Key column “Id” considered bad practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/114728/5905)

Comment: I always alias my tables when I join them so I don't see this as an inconvenience.

Comment: @Icarus: aliasing *columns* so you don't have Id twice in a result set

Comment: @gbn when you say "alias", do you mean  in the select statement?

Comment: @Royi Namir: yes, as per Garrett Vlieger's answer

Comment: @Royi Namir: my link to programmers.sq maybe: 100s of votes and comments

Comment: @Gbn but that's an issue with *any* column for *any* table. One can potentially end up with lots of columns with redundant names just to avoid a very unlikely and easy to detect problem anyway, specially now with so many tools providing intellisense, ORM software, etc.

Comment: @Icarus: go and see the other link on programmers.se Join the bunfight *there*

Answer (score 3):

The best practice for this is to preface with the table name.

This will make it much clearer when joining which field you are referring to in the `SELECT` list.

It also makes accidental bad `JOIN` conditions impossible, i.e.

`JOIN TableA ON ID = TableA.ID`

As a rule, duplicate field names across tables should be avoided unless they represent identical data.

Comment: The accidental join argument is a very good point. I always alias my tables when I join but there's definitely that possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Using the table name in the identity column is slightly redundant, but I find it to be useful and more descriptive especially when performing foreign key joins.  For example, which seems better:

```
SELECT P.PersonID, P.FullName, W.WidgetID, W.WidgetName
FROM Widgets W JOIN
  PersonWidgets PW ON W.WidgetsID = PW.WidgetsID JOIN
  Person P ON P.PersonID = PW.PersonID
```

OR

```
SELECT P.ID as PersonID, P.FullName, W.ID as WidgetID, W.WidgetName
FROM Widgets W JOIN
  PersonWidgets PW ON W.ID = PW.WidgetsID JOIN
  Person P ON P.ID = PW.PersonID
```

The first query is more explicit and leads to less accidental joins.  It also eliminates the need for using aliases in your SELECT list.